# google oauth and variables for ClientId and Secret

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

I am surprised that when I submit a variable with an identical string value it is rejected when the string is accepted in google oauth
For example
$client->setClientSecret('xDDDDDDD-Tcdfgtrrfftr');
is accepted where with the same string value stored in the variable as follows
$client->setClientSecret('{$domain->GooglePlusSecret}');
is rejected.
Anyway to write this to get around it? I serve multiple domains through the same root folder and software and want to set up for individual oauths as well ???

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using PHP here, since that's what your code looks like.

Single quoted strings do not have variables interpreted. The reason your OAuth token doesn't work is because you are using the literal string `{$domain->GooglePlusSecret}`.

You should change your code to either `$client->setClientSecret($domain->GooglePlusSecret);` or `$client->setClientSecret("{$domain->GooglePlusSecret}");`.